# Populating TableView In JavaFX with TableView created in FXML File

Tags: java, class, javafx-2, tableview

I am a newbie in JavaFX and also in java. Guys can you please figure out this code if what is lacking because I can already print the items from the database using the println function.

```
public class TableViewController  implements Initializable{

@FXML
private TableView<studentInfo> tblViewer = new TableView<studentInfo>();
@FXML
private TableColumn colID = new TableColumn();
@FXML
private TableColumn colName = new TableColumn();
@FXML
private TableColumn colAddress = new TableColumn();
@FXML
private TableColumn colAge = new TableColumn();
@FXML
private TableColumn colContact = new TableColumn();
@FXML
private Button cmdTest;

@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
// TODO
System.out.println("READ");
System.out.println(this.getClass().getSimpleName() + ".initialize"); 
cmdTest.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {            
    @Override
    public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
    System.out.println("Button Pressed");                   
    colID.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<studentInfo, Integer>("id"));
    colName.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<studentInfo, String>("name"));
    colAddress.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<studentInfo, String>("address"));
    colAge.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<studentInfo, Integer>("age"));
    colContact.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<studentInfo, String>("contact_num"));
    tblViewer.getItems().setAll(getAllstudentInfo());
    //tblViewer.getColumns().addAll(colID, colName, colAddress, colAge, colContact);
    //System.out.println(tblViewer.getItems().setAll(getAllstudentInfo()));
    }
} );       
}

public class studentInfo{

private final SimpleIntegerProperty idCol;
private final SimpleStringProperty nameCol;
private final SimpleStringProperty addressCol;
private final SimpleIntegerProperty ageCol;
private final SimpleStringProperty contact_numCol;

public studentInfo(Integer id, String name, String address, Integer age, String contact_num){
    this.idCol = new SimpleIntegerProperty(id);
    this.nameCol = new SimpleStringProperty(name);
    this.addressCol = new SimpleStringProperty(address);
    this.ageCol = new SimpleIntegerProperty(age);
    this.contact_numCol = new SimpleStringProperty(contact_num);
  }  
  public Integer getidCol(){
      return idCol.get();
  }
  public void setidCol(Integer id){
      idCol.set(id);      
  }
  public String getnameCol(){
      return nameCol.get();
  }
  public void setnameCol(String name){
      nameCol.set(name);
  }
  public String getaddressCol(){
      return addressCol.get();
  }
  public void setaddressCol(String address){
      addressCol.set(address);
  }
  public Integer getageCol(){
      return ageCol.get();
  }
  public void setageCol(Integer age){
      ageCol.set(age);
  }
  public String getcontact_numCol(){
      return contact_numCol.get();
  }
  public void setcontact_numCol(String contact_num){
      contact_numCol.set(contact_num);
  }        
  }


public List<studentInfo> getAllstudentInfo(){
Connection conn;
List ll = new LinkedList();
Statement st;
ResultSet rs;
String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/java_test";
String user = "root";
String pass = "";
String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";

try{
    Class.forName(driver);
    conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, pass);
    st = conn.createStatement();
    String recordQuery = ("Select * from student");            
    rs = st.executeQuery(recordQuery);
    while(rs.next()){    
        Integer id = rs.getInt("id");
        String name = rs.getString("name");
        String address = rs.getString("address");
        Integer age = rs.getInt("age");
        String contact_num = rs.getString("contact_num");
        ll.add(new studentInfo(id, name, address, age, contact_num));
        System.out.println(id +","+ name +","+ address +","+ age +","+ contact_num +" "+"added.");
    }            
}catch(ClassNotFoundException | SQLException ex){
    Logger.getLogger(TableViewController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
return ll;
}
```

And this is the FXML File:

```
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import java.util.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" prefHeight="594.0" prefWidth="838.0" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml" fx:controller="loadingcsvtotableview.TableViewController">
<children>
<TableView fx:id="tblViewer" prefHeight="521.0" prefWidth="808.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="14.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="15.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="15.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="59.0">
  <columns>
    <TableColumn prefWidth="75.0" text="ID" fx:id="colID" />
    <TableColumn prefWidth="175.0" text="Name" fx:id="colName" />
    <TableColumn prefWidth="330.0" text="Address" fx:id="colAddress" />
    <TableColumn prefWidth="75.0" text="Age" fx:id="colAge" />
    <TableColumn prefWidth="150.0" text="Contact Number" fx:id="colContact" />
  </columns>
 </TableView>
 <Button fx:id="cmdExport" layoutX="14.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="30.0" prefWidth="112.0" text="Export Data" AnchorPane.topAnchor="21.0" />
 <Button fx:id="cmdClose" layoutX="144.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="30.0" prefWidth="112.0" text="Close" AnchorPane.topAnchor="21.0" />
 <Button id="cmdClose" fx:id="cmdTest" layoutX="386.0" layoutY="21.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="30.0" prefWidth="112.0" text="Test" />
 </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

What do Am I Lacking? Please help me guys..

Answer (score 2):

The Property Value Factory doesn't match with any getters and setters function in your bean. So if you set the cell value factory as the next:

```
colID.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<studentInfo, Integer>("id"));
```

The property value factory will look for the function getId(), setId() and idProperty(). The last one returns the property itself, that you have in your bean. Check the [API of PropertyValueFactory](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/control/cell/PropertyValueFactory.html) and the [tutorial of Table View](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/ui_controls/table-view.htm) to go deep on this.

Also do what agonist_ says, you are creating a the column twice.

There are a couple things. You are setting the CellValueFactory every time you click on the button. You need to put it in the initialize not in the button event.

And the function getAllstudentInfo() will block your GUI, because the query it's blocking. You should do this in a background thread.

So replace your `tblViewer.getItems().setAll(getAllstudentInfo());` to something like:

```
Service<ObservableList<studentInfo>> service = new Service<ObservableList<studentInfo>>() {                 
@Override
protected Task<ObservableList<studentInfo>> createTask() {
    return new Task<ObservableList<studentInfo>>() {                            
        @Override
        protected ObservableList<studentInfo> call() throws Exception {
            return FXCollections.observableArrayList(getAllstudentInfo());
        }
    };
}
};
tblViewer.itemsProperty().bind(service.valueProperty());        
service.start();
```

Take a look on [concurrency tutorial of JavaFX 2](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/threads/jfxpub-threads.htm) sure will help you.

Hope it helps.

Comment: This precise and to-the-point answer cleared my confusion. Thank you @Antonio J.

Answer (score 0):

Start by not doing  new instance on your FXML import.
Just

```
@FXML
private TableColumn<String> colContact;
```